# How get movies folder correctly?

Tags: java, android

I'm testing a [code of ScreenRecorder](http://mattsnider.com/video-recording-with-mediaprojectionmanager/) and want store the video file in Movies folder (not emulated). But when i try get this folder using `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + "/video.mp4"` this returns: **/storage/emulated/0/Movies**, folder that i not have acess throught Android UI.

**PS:** tested on Android 7.1.1

Then, how retrieve this folder correctly?

Comment: How you are sure you don't have access to this folder ?

Comment: @Akhil, the folder that i want is the folder "Movies" that already comes created by own Android. Similar to Microsoft Windows that create this folder on formatation.

Comment: I have acess to "Movies" folder, but the file not is created there. Then suspect that **/storage/emulated/0/Movies** is a hidden folder to not see via Android UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have external storage permission?

It should look something like this:

```
public class PermissionUtils {
public static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 2000;

        public static void requestExternal(Activity context) {
        if (!checkExternal(context)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }

      public static boolean checkExternal(Context context) {
        return !(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

}
```

Then just add this in your onCreate(); method:

```
PermissionUtils.requestExternal(this);
```

Comment: i already solved! I not had found location of this folder on my new smartphone that bought yesterday :-)